# Issues faced while doing GIT clone from local server repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-clone

I am trying to setup a git repository as server repository for users to check in and check out their changes.

I am trying to do a poc so that both local and remote repositories are on one machine itself .

Here is what all I did to create repository (as a remote server repository) :

- created a repository using GIT Gui (now I have a directory with .git folder in it).
- ran command **git --bare init --shared myRepo.git** to make it bare for pushing to repository
- now I shared the myRepo.git folder using windows sharing and security.
- And then I mapped this shared folder to a network drive z:

At location d:/myrepository I created a repository(local , that will be on all the machines that will be checking in and out of the server) using GIT Gui.

Here on a newbee GIT user in me comes in picture. I tried various things that may or may not make sense . Please tell why something i tried is right or wrong and if you can help me resolve.
Here is what i tried on local(myrepository) :

```
$ git clone \\z:\myRepo.git 
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: \\z: no address associated with name
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone file:///z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
fatal: 'z:myRepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone file:///myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
fatal: 'C:/Program Files/Git/myRepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone git@\\z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: \\z: no address associated with name
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone ssh://git@\\z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone ssh://z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone ssh://z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone \\z:\myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: \\z: no address associated with name
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

$ git clone ssh://git@172.16.70.177/git1/myRepo.git
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: connect to host 122.16.30.127 port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
```

Please tell what i need to do to make it work.

Thanks,
Mayank Batra

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `git clone z:\`
If you're using git bash:
`git clone /z`

You need to learn more about DOS in this case, not Git. DOS file paths are like I've shown above.

PS: A git repository is similar to this:

```
COMMIT_EDITMSG HEAD           config         hooks          info           objects        refs
FETCH_HEAD     ORIG_HEAD      description    index          logs           packed-refs
```

Comment: Hi Pedro,<br/>

This is what I got :<br/>

$ git clone z:\myRepo.git<br/>
Cloning into 'myRepo'...<br/>
fatal: 'z:myRepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository<br/>
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Open z:\myRepo.git in Windows Explorer. Upload a screenshot somewhere if possible.

Comment: $ git clone z:\    
>   
fatal: could not create work tree dir ''.: No such file or directory

Comment: Where are you trying to create your git repo?

Comment: i am trying to create a repo in my local at location : /d/gitRemote/local (master)

Comment: Did it work? If it did, please accept the answer. Otherwise, let us know.

Comment: now i am getting this : 

$ git clone /z
Cloning into 'z'...
fatal: 'C:/Program Files/Git/z' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

With git bash, it should be:

```
cd c:/path/to/parent/folder
git clone z:/myRepo
# or
git clone file:///z:/myRepo.git
```

That assumes there is no repo folder already existing in the directory "`c:/path/to/parent/folder`", where repo is about to be cloned.

With a cmd session:

```
git clone z:\myRepo
```

---

Not that with [git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd3e186d811a13d8687584856f345a767e3e4d67/Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.txt#L261-L262), you can specify a path which doesn't yet exist for the destination of the clone.

So:

```
git clone z:/myRepo c/path/to/parent/folder/myRepo
```

That will work even if '`parent`' and '`folder`' are two directories which *doesn't exist yet*.

---

> "`git clone $origin foo\bar\baz`" on Windows failed to create the leading directories (i.e. a moral-equivalent of "`mkdir -p`").

See [commit 0f52740](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f5274033ecb0262dc77e4ed48fdb1ab07181bd8) by the [recent GitHub staffer](https://github.com/blog/1691-michael-haggerty-is-a-githubber) [Michael Haggerty (`mhagger`), Nov 2013](https://github.com/mhagger), of [`git imerge` fame](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge), based on [Sebastian Schuberth (`sschuberth`)](https://github.com/sschuberth)'s [patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg218815.html):

### `safe_create_leading_directories()`: on Windows, `\` can separate path components

> When cloning to a directory "C:\foo\bar" from Windows' cmd.exe where
>   "foo" does not exist yet, Git would throw an error like

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'c:\foo\bar'.: No such file or directory
```

> Fix this by not hard-coding a platform specific directory separator into safe_create_leading_directories().
>
> This patch, including its entire commit message, is derived from a patch by [Sebastian Schuberth (`sschuberth`)](https://github.com/sschuberth).